# Switch Statement - line after break and proper indentation

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
    int i,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
       switch(i){
          case 0:
          case 1: if(i<1) break; i=123;
          case 456: j=666; break;
          default: j=777;
       }
       if(j==666) break;
    }
    printf("%i %i\n",i,j);
```

I would like to ask about the proper indentation for the switch statement in this case. From what I understand,

```
    case 0:
    case 1: if(i<1) break; i=123;
```

is equivalent to

```
    case 0: case 1:{
       if(i<1){
          break;
       }
       i=123;
    }
```

However, I do not understand the `i=123` after the break in `case 1`. I have also tried playing with different `N` values and found that as long as `N>=2` I will always get the output of

> 123 666

but I don't see how the value of `i` gets to `456` in order for `case 456` to be triggered.

Comment: Indentation doesn't matter (for the compiler) in C, so asking for "proper" indentation is essentially asking about personal preferences

Comment: You might want to look at the [`-Wimplicit-fallthrough`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) option added to GCC 7.1 — you'll have to search for it.  Or then again, maybe that is beyond what you're ready to deal with now, but it may be useful at some time in the future.  Note that in C, the flow of control continues between `case` labels unless there's a `break` (or `continue` if there's a surrounding loop, or `return`, or `goto`, or any other transfer of control — `longjmp()`, `exit()`, or any other 'no return' function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll format the code to be more readable, and put comments in explaining:

```
int i, j = 0;

for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
   switch (i) {
      case 0:
      case 1:           // Take this case if i is 0 or 1
          if (i < 1)
              break;    // if i < 1 (in other words, it's 0), then break out of switch
          i = 123;      // if i wasn't < 1, then set i to 123 AND fall through to next case
      case 456:         // take this case if i is (originally) 456
                        //    (prior statement still falls through here!)
          j = 666;      // this will happen if either i was 456, or if i was 1
                        //    and then set to 123
          break;
      default:
          j = 777;
   }

   if (j == 666)
       break;    // break out of for loop if i is 666
}

printf("%i %i\n", i, j);
```

Adding a block around the single statement in the `if` clause doesn't change it's behavior. So in this case, this:

```
if (i < 1)
    break;
```

Has the same behavior as this:

```
if (i < 1) {
    break;
}
```

The `break` does not apply to the `if` block. It still applies to the outer `switch`.

Simply, the `switch` just creates a jump table for values of `i`. A `break` within the cases of the switch will exit the "bottom" of the switch. If you get to the end of a `case` and there's no break, then the code continues to execute through the next `case` or `default` if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're confused between the "indentation" with the "expected separation" of case statements.

The `case` statements are essentially just labels. Unless separated through `break` statement, they act as fall-through model.

So, in your case, `i` does not need to be `456` to "trigger" `case 456:` and related statements. A value of `1` will have just the same effect.

> *However, I do not understand the `i=123` after the break in `case 1`.*

Well, that is a conditional `break` statement. The `if` condition will be hit in both the cases of `i` value being `0` or `1`. In case of `i` having a value `0`, the condition check will be success and it will break out of the `switch` statements. Otherwise, it will continue and the assignment statement will be executed.

So, as long as the `N` (other loop condition) is `>=1`, `i` will be set to `123` and `j` to `666`.

> *...but I don't see how the value of `i` gets to `456` in order for `case 456` to be triggered.*

It need not, it's a fall-through action.

---

Regarding the actual importance of "indentation" part, well, compiler does not care about indentation, we, humans to. Proper indentation makes the code readable and maintainable, thus making them valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Let's format this code  more properly:

```
int i,j=0;
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
   switch(i){
   case 0:
   case 1: 
      if(i<1) 
         break; 
      i=123;
   case 456: 
      j=666; 
      break;
   default: 
      j=777;
   }
   if(j==666) break;
}
printf("%i %i\n",i,j);
```

When `i` is 1 the `if (i<1)` condition evaluates to false.  So the `break` does not run, and the statement after the `if` (namely `i=123`) is executed.  It then falls through to `case 456` which sets `j` to 666 and breaks out of the `switch`.  At this point it reaches  `if (j==666)` which evaluates to true and breaks out of the `for`.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code to explain how the `switch` works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    int N=5;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
       printf("i: %d\n",i);
       switch(i){
       case 0:
       case 1: 
          if(i<1){
             printf("in case 1 in if when case: 0 \n"); 
             break;
          } 
          else{   
            printf("in case 1 after if --> in else\n");
          }
       case 3: 
          printf("in case 3\n");
          break;
       default: 
          printf("default : ");
          printf("i: %d\n",i);
       }

       if(i==4){
            printf("after switch\n");
            break;
       }
    }

    printf("after for\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Program output : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDJVo.png

Simply in `switch` block when `case 0` is executed, program control goes to
`case 1` as you do not enter any expression.